# TypeError: Cannot read property 'single' of undefined in multer grid

Tags: reactjs, multer, mern, multer-gridfs-storage, single-file

Please help me , facing problem in multer single file upload
router.post('/file/upload',upload.single('file'), uploadImage);
TypeError: Cannot read property 'single' of undefined
[error found in postRoute.js(api)]

```js
router.post('/file/upload', upload.single('file'), uploadImage);
router.get('/file/:filename', getImage);
```

-multer grid storage connection with mongodb atlas code:

```js
const multer = require("multer");
const {
  GridFsStorage
} = require("multer-gridfs-storage");

const storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: `mongodb://xyz:xyz@blogmern-shard-00-00.6az9f.mongodb.net:27017,blogmern-shard-00-01.6az9f.mongodb.net:27017,blogmern-shard-00-02.6az9f.mongodb.net:27017/blogdata?ssl=true&replicaSet=atlas-hqbs1a-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority`,
  options: {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true
  },
  file: (request, file) => {
    const match = ["image/png", "image/jpg"];
    //if images are not in above format
    if (match.indexOf(file.memeType) === -1)
      //avoid duplicates in img
      return `${Date.now()}-blog-${file.originalname}`;

    //if img gets matched
    return {
      bucketName: "photos",
      filename: `${Date.now()}-blog-${file.originalname}`,
    };
  },
});
const upload = multer({
  storage
});
```

image.js file with api call:

```js
const grid = require('gridfs-stream');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const url = 'http://localhost:8000';
let gfs;
const connect = mongoose.connection;
connect.once('open', () => {
  gfs = grid(connect.db, mongoose.mongo);
  gfs.collection('fs');
})
exports.uploadImage = (request, response) => {
  try {
    if (!request.file)
      return response.status(404).json("File not found");

    const imageURL = `${url}/file/${request.file.filename}`

    response.status(200).json(imageURL);
  } catch (error) {
    response.status(500).json(error);
  }
}
exports.getImage = async(request, response) => {
  try {
    const file = await gfs.files.findOne({
      filename: request.params.filename
    });
    //change file in img
    const readStream = gfs.createReadStream(file.filename);
    readStream.pipe(response);
  } catch (error) {
    response.status(500).json('Failed to fetch image', error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share the code and the error as formatted text, not an image

Comment: @Mureinik I've edited the ques  hope it is clear now, help if possible.

Answer (score 0):

TypeError: Cannot read property 'single' of undefined implies that `upload` does not exist.

What happens when you run `console.log(upload);` before that router route registration, like this?

```js
console.log(upload);
...
router.post('/file/upload', upload.single('file'), uploadImage);
```

Comment: I'm getting only this error: "router.post('/file/upload',upload.single('file'), uploadImage);
                                  ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'single' of undefined"